# angular 2+ force first item to be selected in a drop down

Tags: angular, html-select

The following code is doing what it is supposed to do:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="file_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">File names:</label>
      <select id="file_name"  class="col-sm-8" [(ngModel)]="fileName" name="file_name" required>
        <option value="run">use the run name</option>
        <option value="other">custom- please specify a name below</option>
        <option value="input">use the file input name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="fileName === 'other'">
      <label for="custom_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">File name:</label>
      <input  class="col-sm-8" type="text" id="custom_name" ngModel name="other_custom_name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="fileName === 'run'">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter file name:</label>
      <label  class="col-sm-8" id="run_name">{{ this.runName }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="fileName === 'input'">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">File name:</label>
      <label  class="col-sm-8" id="input_name">{{ this.inputDeckName }}</label>
    </div>
```

If I select the second option, an input is displayed:

[image]

But when I start the app no item is selected:

[image]

I would like the first item to be automatically selected:
[image]

Setting the relative option to selected does not work:

```
<option value="run" selected>use the run name</option>
```

Can you help?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller define the property fileName and set it to value of the option you want to be selected. In this case you should do following:

```
public fileName: string = 'run';
```

Comment: Thank you, in Angular 2+ there are not controllers but I have implemented your suggestion in my typescript and initialised the value in the ngOnChanges() lifecycle. It worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

**selected** property works when you are not using `ngModel` only. When using `ngModel` the default value must be assigned to that `ngModel`

**TS file**

```
fileName: string = 'run';
```

Comment: Thank you, Sivaramakrishnan. I have accepted Arif's answer has it came first and put my in the right path but thank you for taking the time to answer my question.